# Как сравнить даты в MYSQL?

Tags: javascript, mysql

Дата записывается в формате - 2021-11-05; Вызвав запрос

> SELECT * FROM test WHERE CURRENT_DATE() >= "2021-11-05"

Если имеется в бд 2020-11-05, то он сочтет это верным и отобразит запись.
Что с этим можно сделать?

Comment: Во-первых, какой тип столбца, в который записывается дата?

Comment: Во-вторых, вы сравниваете текущую дату с прописанной в запросе строкой и даже не пытаетесь прочитать дату из таблицы. Так как сегодня 5 ноября 2021 года, то такое условие конечно же будет верным всегда для всех строк

Comment: тип столбца - date

Comment: Ну значит нужно делать что-то вроде `WHERE имястолбца >= "2021-11-05"` и не трогать CURRENT_DATE

Comment: мне нужно сравнивать сегодняшнюю дату и из столбца

Comment: Каким именно образом сравнивать?

Comment: Необходимо сравнивать текущую дату с событием из столбца (время), т.е. чтобы при вводе запроса была запись фестиваля, который будет происходить в будущем, т.е. если текущее время меньше времени события, то должна отобразиться запись со столбцами фестиваля

Comment: «текущее время меньше времени события» → ну значит `WHERE CURRENT_DATE() <= имястолбца`